# ¿Como configurar Visual Studio Code para Java?

Tags: java, vscode

en primera, me gustaria saludar a todos los que integran esta gran comunidad de desarrolladores   y felicitarlos por crear tan excelente comunidad.

Pues bien,el problema que hoy se me presenta es que al recién empezar con java he decidido utilizar este editor para realizar mis practicas, pero hasta ahora no he podido hacer las configuraciones para java

Hasta ahora solo he seguido las guías para instalar los plugins básicos de java disponibles para el editor.

Agradeciendo de antemano cualquier ayuda y esperando que alguien pueda orientarme paso a paso de hacer que VSC sea 100% funcional para java.
Me despido cordialmente.

Comment: Hola Gabriel, podrías proporcionar mas información a tu pregunta, que has investigado, que has intentado, en que estás fallando especificamente? Sin mas información es un poco complicado que alguien te pueda proporcionar ayuda.

Comment: Te recomiendo visitar **[ask]**

Comment: Hola Kacospro pues. hasta ahora he seguido los siguientes pasos:
1.instalar VSC 2. instalar el paquete de extensiones que segun la web de VSC son necesarias para java. 3.despues creo un nuevo archivo .java, pero el problema es que justo al crear el archivo 
en el me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error: 
"Classpath is incomplete" Only sintax errors will be reported" y al tratar de realizar la compilacion me dice  que no encuentra  el comando javac a pesar de que ya configure la variable de entorno en Windows. 
Bueno ojala la informacion sea suficiente y puedas ayudarme. Saludos

Comment: Puedes [edit] tu pregunta e incluir esa información :)

Comment: Por curiosidad, por qué no estás utilizando Netbeans o Eclipse?

Comment: Por qué sabes que no has podido hacer las configuraciones? Qué errores tienes? Qué mensajes de error encuentras? Recuerda añadir toda la información relevante **editando** tu pregunta. Gracias!

Comment: Hola a todos, les comento que ya pude resolver el problema. Buscando entre las extensiones de VSC encontré una llamada AIO Compiler esta me ayudo a resolver los problemas para compilar y ejecutar las aplicaciones.                                                            tomare en cuenta sus consejos para la siguiente  ser lo mas especifico posible en mis consultas. Me despido agradeciendo a todos sus respuestas y consejos bye:)